# i have 2 RadioButton in my webform- Why I can check both?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 RadioButton in my WebForm - Why I can check both?

I want that if I check one - the other will be un-checked (like in WinForm)

how to do it (asp.net)?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**RadioButton.GroupName Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname.aspx)

Gets or sets the name of the group that the radio button belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

They both need to have the same `name` attribute for this to work.

As [CD has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717988/i-have-2-radiobutton-in-my-webform-why-i-can-check-both/4718028#4718028), this can be set inside of your aspx page using the `GroupName` attribute on an ASP.NET radio control. This will render the `name` attribute in the outputted HTML markup.

Comment: how i can give same name to control ?